# concurrent handling in thin, unicorn, puma, webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency, thin, unicorn, puma

If I have the following action in a controller

```
def give_a
 print a
 a = a+1
end
```

What happens in each webserver when a request comes and when multiple requests are recieved?

I know that webrick and thin and single threaded so I guess that means that the a request doesn't get processed until the current request is done.

What happens in concurrent webservers such as puma or unicorn (perhaps others)
If there are 2 requests coming and 2 unicorn threads handle them, would both responses give the same `a` value? (in a situation when both request enter the method in the same time)

or does it all depend on what happens on the server itself and the access to data is serial?

Is there a way to have a mutex/semaphore for the concurrent webservers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, the rails application makes a `YourController.new` with each request env.

from what you post, it is not possible to see, what `a` means. when it is some shared class variable, then it is mutuable state and could be modified from both request threads.

Comment: thanks, are the requests to the database in a single queue (in a standard app)? - if `a` is a value taken from the database

Comment: queue? no, there is no queue! if you want to guarentee, that values don't change during request, you need to lock the database. this is a very bad practice, called pessimistic locking. what you usually do is optimistic locking using where clauses.